# Format float\double numbers to CString with zero filling and preset number of digits

Tags: c++, formatting, floating-point, cstring

I am looking for a simple method to format the following float\double numbers **to a CString**.
I was hoping to use CString.Format(), but alternatives are welcome as well, as long as it ends up being a CString.

```
3.45
112.2
```

To the following format:

```
00003450
00112200
```

Notice there should be **no decimal point**.
Can this be done simply, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CString myString;
myString.Format(_T("%08d"), static_cast<int>(num * 1000.0 + 0.5));
```

Alternatively:

```
//...
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//...
ostringstream s;
s << setfill('0') << setw(8) << static_cast<int>(num * 1000.0 + 0.5);

CString myString(s.str().c_str());
//...
```

Refs:

1. [CString::Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms908328.aspx)
2. [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: How do I convert to CString in the end? (without printing...)

Comment: I think it should be s.str().c_str() and not c.str.c_str()

Comment: @Jonathan: edited. I think top one is more like what you were after.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << int(int(YourNumber)*1000+.5);
```

should do the trick.

Edit: Added rounding.
Edit: Second int() cast for silencing obscure warnings :-)

Comment: How do I convert to CString in the end? (without printing...)

Comment: you'll get a warning on many compilers multiplying an `int` by a `double`

Comment: I am multiplying an int with an int (1000) and adding a double. Anyway, fixed it. @Jonathan, sorry, I read to fast.

Answer (score 2):

`f` does work.

```
void f(double a) {
    const int a1000 = static_cast<int>(a * 1000 + 0.5);
    assert(a1000 < 100000000); 
    const int b = a1000 + 100000000;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << b;
    std::cout << ss.str().c_str() + 1; //remove first 1;
}

int main() {
    f(3.45);
    f(112.2);
}
```

Comment: How do I convert to CString in the end? (without printing...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [Boost.Format](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#syntax):

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

CString f(double d)
{
   return str(boost::format("%1$=08.0f") % (1000*d)).c_str();
}
```